# Is there a closed-form solution of this ODE (computing a flow on an ellipse)?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Can we find an explicit closed-form solution of the following ODE?

$\beta:[0,\epsilon] \to (0,2\pi]$, $\beta(0)=\beta_0$, and
$$\dot \beta(t)=\frac{c}{R(\beta(t))+c_0},$$ where $c,c_0$ are constants, and
$$R(\theta):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\big(e \cos(\theta)\big)^2}}, 0<e<1.$$

---

The motivation for this ODE comes from trying to compute a flow of a given vector field on an ellipse: $(R\theta),\theta))$ are essentially the polar coordinates of the ellipse, $e$ is its
eccentricity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{d \beta}{dt}=\frac{c}{R(\beta(t))+c_0}\quad;\quad
R(\beta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\big(e \cos(\beta)\big)^2}}$$

$$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\big(e \cos(\beta)\big)^2}}+c_0\right)\frac{d \beta}{dt}=c$$

$$\int \frac{d\beta}{\sqrt{1-\big(e \cos(\beta)\big)^2}}+c_0\beta=c(t-t_0)$$

$$t=t_0+\frac{1}{c}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-e^2}}F\left(\beta\:\Bigg|\:{\frac{e^2}{e^2-1}} \right)+c_0\beta \right)$$
$F$ is the elliptic integral of the first kind.
With initial condition $\beta(0)=\beta_0$ :

$$\boxed{t(\beta)=\frac{1}{c\:\sqrt{1-e^2}}\left( F\left(\beta\:\Bigg|\:{\frac{e^2}{e^2-1}}\right)-F\left(\beta_0\:\Bigg|\:{\frac{e^2}{e^2-1}}\right) \right)+\frac{c_0}{c}(\beta-\beta_0)}$$
This is the solution $t$ as a function of $\beta$.

The inverse function $\beta(t)$ cannot be written with a finite number of available standard functions. Numerical calculus is recommended.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be sure: Does the inverse of the elliptic integral $F$ also does not have a closed-form elementary expression? (While searching I got to the term 'Jacobi amplitude').

Comment: I just found this: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0010465515001733

Comment: Of course the inverse of elliptic integrals can be expressed in terms of Jacobi elliptic integrals. This could be used in your case if $c_0=0$. But I suppose that $c_0\neq 0$. The presence of the additive term $c_0\beta$ causes to the equation cannot be inverted.

Comment: Hi Jean ! One more nice solution. How are you ?

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici. Hi Claude ! " Bon pied, bon oeil". As always I enjoy hearing from you.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\dot{\beta}{(\theta)} &= \frac{c}{R(\beta{(\theta)}) + c_0} \Leftrightarrow \\
&\Leftrightarrow \left(R(\beta{(\theta)}) + c_0\right)\dot{\beta}{(\theta)} = c \Leftrightarrow \\
&\Leftrightarrow \int\limits_0^\theta\left(R(\beta{(\tau)}) + c_0\right)\dot{\beta}{(\tau)}d\tau = c\int\limits_0^\theta d\tau = c\theta 
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, we have to evaluate the integral

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int\limits_0^\theta\left(R(\beta{(\tau)}) + c_0\right)\dot{\beta}{(\tau)}d\tau &= \left|u = \beta{(\tau)} \Rightarrow du = \dot{\beta}(\tau)d\tau\right| = \\
&= \int\limits_{\beta{(0)}}^{\beta{(\theta)}}\left(R(u) + c_0\right)du = \\
&= \int\limits_{\beta{(0)}}^{\beta{(\theta)}}\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-\left(e\cos{u}\right)^2}} + c_0(\beta{(\theta)} - \beta{(0)}) = \left|\right|
\end{aligned}
$$